# Log4j2 pattern layout + negative number at Conversion Pattern

Tags: java, log4j2

I am using **log4j2 2.5** and trying to alter the pattern layout in order to shorten the package output.

My package naming pattern is like `com.mycompany.myproject.myapp`. Using the `%C` or `%c` formatting options, I am trying to remove the **first three** components of the package path (`com.mycompany.myproject`) and leave the rest as is.

According to [log4j 2.x manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html), when using **negative** number:

> If negative, the layout removes the corresponding number of leftmost
>   logger name components.

So my PatternLayout includes `%C{-3}`:

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] [%C{-3}] (%F:%M:%L) - %m%n"/>
```

Unfortunately the output I get is full of `.-` instead of removing the first 3 parts of the package structure. Output  `-.-.-.-.MyClass`

**UPDATE**: adding log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] [%c{-3}] (%F:%M:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="info"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**UPDATE 2**: added dummy Main class , pom.xml and output

**Main.java**

```
package com.example.test.log4jtester;


import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Main {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class.getName());


    public static void main(String[] args){                              

        LOGGER.info("java.vendor: {} ",System.getProperties().getProperty("java.vendor"));
        LOGGER.info("java.version: {} ",System.getProperties().getProperty("java.version"));
        LOGGER.info("os.arch: {} ",System.getProperties().getProperty("os.arch"));
        LOGGER.info("os.name: {} ",System.getProperties().getProperty("os.name"));
        LOGGER.info("os.version: {} ",System.getProperties().getProperty("os.version"));

    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Log4jTester</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**output**

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ Log4jTester ---
2016-11-30 13:17:21,606 INFO  [main] [-.-.-.-.Main] (Main.java:main:32) - java.vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2016-11-30 13:17:21,607 INFO  [main] [-.-.-.-.Main] (Main.java:main:33) - java.version: 1.8.0_60 
2016-11-30 13:17:21,607 INFO  [main] [-.-.-.-.Main] (Main.java:main:34) - os.arch: amd64 
2016-11-30 13:17:21,607 INFO  [main] [-.-.-.-.Main] (Main.java:main:35) - os.name: Windows 10 
2016-11-30 13:17:21,607 INFO  [main] [-.-.-.-.Main] (Main.java:main:36) - os.version: 10.0
```